# How to get first time from server by php and put in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, date, time

How can I get first time from server by php?

I've tested this code but it does not work. It gets the time but it is not counting? What's the problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function GetClock(){
            d = new Date(<?php echo date("y, n, j, G, i, s");?>);
            nhour = d.getHours();
            nmin = d.getMinutes();
            nsec = d.getSeconds();
            if(nhour ==  0) {
                ap = " AM";nhour = 12;
            }  else if(nhour <= 11) {
                ap = " AM";
            }  else if(nhour == 12) {
                ap = " PM";
            }  else if(nhour >= 13) {
                ap = " PM";nhour -= 12;
            }

            if(nmin <= 9) {
                nmin = "0" +nmin;
            } if(nsec <= 9) {
                nsec = "0" +nsec;
            }

            document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML=""+nhour+":"+nmin+":"+nsec+ap+"";
            setTimeout("GetClock()", 1000); 
        } 

        window.onload=GetClock;
</script>
```

Comment: What is getting in variable d?

Comment: Is that code from a PHP or a JS file?

Comment: `<?php echo date("y, n, j, G, i, s");?>` gives something like `13, 6, 5, 10, 52, 00`.

Comment: this code id js but it has a short php code inside

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

The question is why are you using PHP to write a datetime into the `Date` object in JS?

The PHP will only write out the time at the point at which the page renders, it will never change again.

You are then setting your counter based on a Javascript `setTimeout` every 1 second, expecting the clock to increment in seconds, but it is always based on the same original time (the page render time) and is always incremented by 1 second.

For example.  The page loads at 12:00:00 on June 3 2013.  Your code looks like this:

```
d = new Date(13, 6, 3, 12, 0, 0);
```

at the time the pages loads (if you view source)

1 second later the `setTimeout` fires and renders the clock at 12:0:01, based on the starting time in the date object.

**But** your starting time never changes, so each further second that passes and triggers `setTimeout` will base the calculations on `12:00:00` not the current time

### TLDR; and answer

Remove the PHP!

```
d = new Date();
```

Alternatively, if you absolutely **have** to use server time.  You would need to initialise the date object as you have done, but then store a count of how many seconds have passed and calculate the difference

Comment: What if it needs a server time?

Comment: If you **have** to use server time, you would have to initialise the `Date` object with the php, but then you would have to count the number of times that the `setTimeout` triggers so you could base your calculations on an incrementing number of seconds from the original